# Segmentation fault error in insertion operation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree, insertion

I want to write a generic binary search tree.
I get a segmentation fault when i try to execute my insert function.

So here are (I think) the relevant code snippets:

```
/* node.h */
typedef struct {
   unsigned int elemSize;
   void *value;
   void *leftChild;    
   void *rightChild;   
   void (*freefn)(void *);     // free function
} Node;

void newNode(Node *node, unsigned int elemSize, void *value) {
    node->elemSize = elemSize;
    node->value = value;
    node->leftChild = NULL;
    node->rightChild = NULL;
}

void nodeSetValue(Node *node, void *value) {
    node->value = value;
}

void nodeSetLeftChild(Node *node, Node *leftChild) {
    node->leftChild = leftChild;
}

/* btree.h */
typedef struct {
    unsigned int elemSize;
    Node *root;                     
    void (*freefn)(void *);         // free function    
    int (*cmpfn)(void *, void *);   // compare function
} Btree;


void btreeInsertHelper(Node *node, void *value, int (*cmpfn)(void *, void *)) {
    if(node == NULL) {
        nodeSetValue(node, value);
        return;
    }
    int cmpresult = cmpfn(value, nodeGetValue(node));
    if(cmpresult >= 0) {
        Node *rightChild = nodeGetRightChild(node);
        if(rightChild == NULL) {
            rightChild = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
            nodeSetRightChild(node, rightChild);
        }
        btreeInsertHelper(rightChild, value, cmpfn);
    } else {
        Node *leftChild = nodeGetLeftChild(node);
        if(leftChild == NULL) {
            leftChild = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
            nodeSetLeftChild(node, leftChild);
        }
        btreeInsertHelper(leftChild, value, cmpfn);
    }
    return;
}

void btreeInsert(Btree *btree, void *value) {
    if(btree->root == NULL) {
        Node *root = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode(root, sizeof(btree->elemSize), value);
        btree->root = root;
        return;
     } else {
        btreeInsertHelper(btree->root, value, btree->cmpfn);
        return;
   }
}

/* test.c */
int intCmp(void *a, void *b) {
    return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}

int main() {

    Btree btree;
    newBtree(&btree, sizeof(int), NULL, intCmp);

    int a = 10;
    int b = 9;
    int c = 11;
    int d = 3;

    btreeInsert(&btree, &a);
    btreeInsert(&btree, &b);
    btreeInsert(&btree, &c);
    btreeInsert(&btree, &d);

    return 0;
}
```

I've got the feeling that I'm passing the wrong references at some points

Comment: Do you know where the segmentation fault occurs ?

Comment: Where is newBtree() defined?

Comment: Code example neither minimal nor complete. ;-)

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: post newBtree() function.

Comment: Pretty much a debugging exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple editor for my work. 
Now, after installing an IDE and after debugging my program, i found out that at the beginning of the btreeInsertHelper function 'node' never has become NULL. Instead, I had to check node->value for being NULL. After overjumping the if-clause, the compare function compared 'value' to a NULL value.

Thanks for your help. For the sake of completeness, my newBtree-function:

```
void newBtree(Btree *btree, unsigned int elemSize, void(freefn (void*),int(cmpfn)(void *,void *)) {
    btree->elemSize = elemSize;
    btree->freefn = freefn;
    btree->cmpfn = cmpfn;
    btree->root = NULL;
}
```